# How to have a close icon show up on <input> active state

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a input field with search icon. When the input field is pressed/focused I want to have a close icon show up on the input box as in the below image

[image: InActive State]

[image: Active State]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUPpQ/3/)

```
<div id="search-controls">
   <input type="text" class="search-box in-acvtive" placeholder="e.g. restaurant name, cuisine" />
</div>

#search-controls {
    height: 68px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#search-controls input.ui-input-text {
    height: 26px;
    background: url('../img/search-icon.png') 99.5% center no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 14px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px -5px #BBB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px -5px #BBB;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 10px -5px #BBB;
    padding: 6px 5px 0 5px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

#search-controls input.ui-input-text.ui-focus {
    border: 1px solid #9E0249;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
    moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    background: url('../img/search-active-icon.png') 100% center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WUPpQ/6/)

***HTML***

```
<div id="header" class="search" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div id="search-controls">
        <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="e.g. restaurant name, cuisine" />
        <span> x </span>        
    </div><!-- /search-controls -->
</div>​
```

***CSS***

```css
#search-controls span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    right: 35px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    background: #bbb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font: 400 20px/22px 'Lucida Console', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search-controls input.ui-input-text.ui-focus ~ span {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: trying to replace "x" with img. not displaying properly http://jsfiddle.net/WUPpQ/8/

Comment: Thanks Zoltan. I'm trying to use that"x" img as a clear button. Do u know how to do that. I'm trying something like <a href="index.html" data-role="button"data-mimi="true" data-inline="true"><img src="img/search-clear.png"/></a>. I replaced <span> with <a>. Still couldn't get it working

Comment: you have to use JS for that - attach a `click/tap` listener to your button and when it occurs clear the input

Comment: is that the only option? any ways to take adv. of jquery mobile features like "delete" button..you know ..